# Real-time transcription Google Cloud Speech API with gRPC from Electron

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, electron

What I want to achieve is the same real-time transcript process as Web Speech API but using Google Cloud Speech API.

The main goal is to transcribe live recording through an Electron app with Speech API using gRPC protocol.

This is a simplified version of what I implemented:

```js
const { desktopCapturer } = window.require('electron');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

const client = speech.v1({
  projectId: 'my_project_id',
  credentials: {
    client_email: 'my_client_email',
    private_key: 'my_private_key',
  },
});

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }, (error, sources) => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      let arrayBuffer;
      fileReader.onloadend = () => {
        arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
        let speechStreaming = client
          .streamingRecognize({
            config: {
              encoding: speech.v1.types.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
              languageCode: 'en-US',
              sampleRateHertz: 44100,
            },
            singleUtterance: true,
          })
          .on('data', (response) => response);

        speechStreaming.write(arrayBuffer);
      };

      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(stream);
    });
});
```

The error response from Speech API is that the audio stream is too slow and we are not sending it in real-time.

I feel that the reason is that I passed the stream without any formatting or object initialization so the streaming recognition cannot be performed.

Comment: Have you managed to work this with electron? I have the same task.

Comment: I'm also seeking real-time transcription in Electron. I don't have an answer to your specific question of how to use Google Cloud Speech in Electron, but I thought I'd mention an alternative: create an iframe to "otter.ai" (transcription service with 600 minutes free each month), have the user sign in (uses open-auth sign-in so it's very fast), then insert custom code into the iframe (webview preload) letting you launch transcription when desired and retrieve the text transcribed in it. Unusual approach, but Otter's transcription is quite good, and the 600 free mins per-user per-month is nice.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [node-record-lpcm16](https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16) module to record audio and pipe directly to a speech recognition system like Google.

In the repository, there is an [example](https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16/blob/master/examples/witai.js) using wit.ai.

For Google Speech recognition, you may use something like that:

```
'use strict'
const { SpeechClient } = require('@google-cloud/speech')
const recorder = require('node-record-lpcm16')

const RECORD_CONFIG = {
  sampleRate: 44100,
  recorder: 'arecord'
}

const RECOGNITION_CONFIG = {
  config: {
    sampleRateHertz: 44100,
    language: 'en-US',
    encoding: 'LINEAR16'
  },
  interimResults: true
}

const client = new SpeechClient(/* YOUR CREDENTIALS */)

const recognize = () => {
  client
    .streamingRecognize(RECOGNITION_CONFIG)
    .on('error', err => {
      console.error('Error during recognition: ', err)
    })
    .once('writing', data => {
      console.log('Recognition started!')
    }
    .on('data', data => {
      console.log('Received recognition data: ', data)
    }
}

const recording = recorder.record(RECORD_CONFIG)
recording
  .stream()
  .on('error', err => {
     console.error('Error during recognition: ', err)
  .pipe(recognize)
```

Answer (score 0):

This official sample project on Github appears to match what you're looking for: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/infiniteStreaming.js

> This application demonstrates how to perform infinite streaming using the streamingRecognize operation with the Google Cloud Speech API.

See also [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058020/real-time-transcription-google-cloud-speech-api-with-grpc-from-electron/57192884#comment100894566_47058020) for an alternative in Electron, using OtterAI's transcription service. (it's the approach I'm going to try soon)